# Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to get duplicate objects within an array of objects. Let's say the object is like below.

```
values = [
  { id: 10, name: 'someName1' },
  { id: 10, name: 'someName2' },
  { id: 11, name: 'someName3' },
  { id: 12, name: 'someName4' }
];
```

Duplicate objects should return like below:

```
duplicate = [
  { id: 10, name: 'someName1' },
  { id: 10, name: 'someName2' }
];
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Trying how? You haven't shown us any code that attempts to solve this. A web search for array duplicates should have given you a good start point

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to make a counter lookup table based on the `id` key, then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove any items that appeared only once in the lookup table. Time complexity is O(n).

```js
const values = [{id: 10, name: 'someName1'}, {id: 10, name: 'someName2'}, {id: 11, name:'someName3'}, {id: 12, name: 'someName4'}];

const lookup = values.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.id] = ++a[e.id] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(values.filter(e => lookup[e.id]));
```

You can simplify this if your browser supports `Object.groupBy`:

```js
const values = [{id: 10, name: 'someName1'}, {id: 10, name: 'someName2'}, {id: 11, name:'someName3'}, {id: 12, name: 'someName4'}];

const lookup = Object.groupBy(values, e => e.id);
console.log(values.filter(e => lookup[e.id].length > 1));
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code?I confuse.You don't have any equality in your code how this work?And why `a` in every iteration show the same object?I need detailed analysis of your code.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the docs for `reduce` and `filter` if you haven't yet. I use `reduce` to build an object mapping of each object's `id` to the count of its `occurrences - 1`. `a` is the accumulator object which is passed from one callback to the next by `reduce`. `filter` uses the truthiness of `lookup[e.id]` to determine if an element is unique. If the lookup entry is 0 (falsey), it was only seen once and `filter` omits it from the result set, else it's kept.

Comment: Actually I know about reduce (not an expert but know) and filter.And know how they work.But it is to hard to understanding your code.But with your explanation everything has become little bit easier :) Thank you.

Comment: This is extremely clever code and I don't think your explanation does it justice @ggorlen ! To explain exactly what is going on inside the reduce, here goes: each item in the array is processed by the arrow function, and either creates a property in the lookup (new item), or increments the counter (we hit a duplicate). Exactly how this works is as follows: a[e.id] = ++a[e.id] || 0 will only increment a property using ++ if it already exists. If it doesn't, then it will fall through the OR (||) and create a property with value 0.

Comment: @ggorlen Have can we compare multiple fields ID and Name?

Comment: @Vivek sure, either combine multiple fields into a key (probably use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so you aren't stuck with delimited string keys) or use a nested object, one layer per property. There should be other threads ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54625474/6243352) looks good on quick glance) that deal with forming the grouping. Given a customer grouping, you can use the same frequency count and filter shown above.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for getting back , I checked both the links however finding it slightly challenging to comprehend. The requirement is such that I should be able to compare multiple properties and print all the matching values. Your code works like a charm for a single property , Would be grateful if you could help me with a code snippet to compare and print multiple duplicate properties.

Comment: @Vivek That's a bit too out of scope for this thread -- it's confusing for future visitors if I edit my answer to include new problems from the comments that aren't part of the original question. I'd either ask a new question if there's no dupe, keep hunting to find a dupe, or use the links I shared and build it yourself. You can probably get away with something as simple as changing the above code to ```a[`${e.id} ${e.name}`]``` or whatever the multiple properties you want to group on are.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Let's say you have:

```
arr = [
    { id:10, name: 'someName1' },
    { id:10, name: 'someName2' },
    { id:11, name: 'someName3' },
    { id:12, name: 'someName4' }
]
```

So, to get unique items:

```
unique = arr
     .map(e => e['id'])
     .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
     .filter(obj=> arr[obj])
     .map(e => arr[e]);
```

Then, result will be

```
unique = [
     { id:10, name: 'someName1' },
     { id:11, name: 'someName3' },
     { id:12, name: 'someName4' }
]
```

And, to get duplicate ids:

```
duplicateIds = arr
     .map(e => e['id'])
     .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) !== i && i)
     .filter(obj=> arr[obj])
     .map(e => arr[e]["id"])
```

List of IDs will be

```
duplicateIds = [10]
```

Thus, to get duplicates objects:

```
duplicate = arr.filter(obj=> dublicateIds.includes(obj.id));
```

Now you have it:

```
duplicate = [
    { id:10, name: 'someName1' },
    { id:10, name: 'someName2' }
]
```

Thanks https://reactgo.com/removeduplicateobjects/

Comment: How do we find out duplicates for multiple properties?

Comment: I am not what do you mean @Vivek ,, if you have examples for the inputs and the expected output, so I can help!

Comment: Thanks for getting back , I am using the exact same example in your answer. In your examples , we are finding out duplicates based on ID. If we have to find out duplicated ID and name properties , what changes need to be done? any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can do that easily by replacing ".map(e => e['id'])" by ".map(e => e['id']+'_'+e['name'])"

Comment: And how do we call it?

Comment: Use of `indexOf` inside a `map` makes this a O(n^2) algorithm. Using the `countBy` or the `groupBy` method above is easier to understand and works in O(n).

Comment: Your solution for finding unique items is exactly what we were trying to conclude and literally had to change indexOf to lastIndexOf and achieved what we needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

With lodash you can solve this with [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) and [`countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#countBy) for complexity of `O(n)`:

```js
const data = [{ id: 10,name: 'someName1' }, { id: 10,name: 'someName2' }, { id: 11,name: 'someName3' }, { id: 12,name: 'someName4' } ]

const counts = _.countBy(data, 'id')
console.log(_.filter(data, x => counts[x.id] > 1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could do the same with ES6 like so:

```js
const data = [{ id: 10,name: 'someName1' }, { id: 10,name: 'someName2' }, { id: 11,name: 'someName3' }, { id: 12,name: 'someName4' } ]

const countBy = (d, id) => d.reduce((r,{id},i,a) => (r[id] = a.filter(x => x.id == id).length, r),{})
const counts = countBy(data, 'id')
console.log(data.filter(x => [x.id] > 1))
```

Answer (score 8):

You haven't clarified whether two objects with different ids, but the same "name" count as a duplicate. I will assume those do not count as a duplicate; in other words, only objects with the same id will count as duplicate.

```
let ids = {};
let dups = [];

values.forEach((val)=> {
  if (ids[val.id]) {
    // we have already found this same id
    dups.push(val)
  } else {
    ids[val.id] = true;
  }
})
return dups;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array to store unique elements and use filter on values to only return duplicates.

```
const unique = []

const duplicates = values.filter(o => {

   if(unique.find(i => i.id === o.id && i.name === o.name)) {
     return true
   }

   unique.push(o)
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you can use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) to group elements by their `id`. Than [`_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) out groups that have less than two members, and [`_.flatten()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatten) the results:

```js
const values = [{id: 10, name: 'someName1'}, {id: 10, name: 'someName2'}, {id: 11, name:'someName3'}, {id: 12, name: 'someName4'}];

const result = _.flow([
  arr => _.groupBy(arr, 'id'), // group elements by id
  g => _.filter(g, o => o.length > 1), // remove groups that have less than two members
  _.flatten // flatten the results to a single array
])(values);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative based in @ggorlen solution with new Map() as accumulator (for better performance) and without unary operator `++` ([not advised by default in projects with ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus)).

```js
const values = [{ id: 10, name: "someName1" }, { id: 10, name: "someName2" }, { id: 11, name: "someName3" }, { id: 12, name: "someName4" },];

const lookup = values.reduce((a, e) => {
  a.set(e.id, (a.get(e.id) ?? 0) + 1);
  return a;
}, new Map());

console.log(values.filter(e => lookup.get(e.id) > 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function checkDuplicateInObject(propertyName, inputArray) {
  var seenDuplicate = false,
  testObject = {};

  inputArray.map(function(item) {
  var itemPropertyName = item[propertyName];    
  if (itemPropertyName in testObject) {
  testObject[itemPropertyName].duplicate = true;
  item.duplicate = true;
  seenDuplicate = true;
 }
 else {
   testObject[itemPropertyName] = item;
   delete item.duplicate;
 }
});

 return seenDuplicate;
}
```

referred from : http://www.competa.com/blog/lets-find-duplicate-property-values-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/