# How to group an array of objects based on multiple keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array as follows

```
 [
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 3,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 3,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 4,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 4,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 5,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T16:22:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 5,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:23:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 6,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 6,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I want to group it by `WarehouseId`, `ShippingCarrierId` and PostalCodeType.
Each objec will have chlid array of objects for Timestart, TimeEnd etc

How can I achieve this

output like :

```
PickupTimeTable: [{
            WarehouseId: 1,
            ShippingCarrierId: 1,
            PostalCodeType: 'ShipToCustomer',
            PickupTimeSlots: [{
                    StartTime: '06:00:00.0000000',
                    EndTime: '15:59:00.0000000',
                    Slot: 'PM',
                    PickupTime: '17:00:00.0000000',
                    DaysToAdd: 0
                },
                {
                    StartTime: '16:00:00.0000000',
                    EndTime: '23:59:00.0000000',
                    Slot: 'AM',
                    PickupTime: '11:00:00.0000000',
                    DaysToAdd: 1
                },
                {
                    StartTime: '00:00:00.0000000',
                    EndTime: '05:59:00.0000000',
                    Slot: 'AM',
                    PickupTime: '11:00:00.0000000',
                    DaysToAdd: 0
                },
            ]
        }, ]
```

Comment: What's your attempt?

Comment: There are many ways to tackle this. One way is to use `reduce` function [more detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: create object array with distinct WarehouseId, ShippingCarrierId and PostalCodeType and then do foreach and add objects

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how your output would look like? A 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create an accumulator object with a new key for each unique combination of those 3 keys seperated by `-`. Then based on this new key merge the array using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to separate the keys you need in the `PickupTimeSlots` to a `rest` variable. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the final array:

```js
const slots=[{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToCustomer","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToCustomer","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToCustomer","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":2,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToCustomer","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":2,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToCustomer","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":3,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":3,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":4,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":4,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":5,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T16:22:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":5,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:23:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":6,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":6,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":1,"ShippingCarrierId":1,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":2,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"PM","DaysToAdd":0,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"},{"WarehouseId":2,"ShippingCarrierId":2,"PostalCodeType":"ShipToDS","TimeStart":"1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","TimeEnd":"1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z","PickupTimeSlot":"AM","DaysToAdd":1,"PickupTime":"1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"}]

const merged = slots.reduce((r, { WarehouseId, ShippingCarrierId, PostalCodeType,...rest }) => {
  const key = `${WarehouseId}-${ShippingCarrierId}-${PostalCodeType}`;
  r[key] = r[key] || { WarehouseId, ShippingCarrierId, PostalCodeType, PickupTimeSlots: [] };
  r[key]["PickupTimeSlots"].push(rest)
  return r;
}, {})

const timeTable = Object.values(merged)
console.log(timeTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` function from lodash - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy

```
let groupBy = _.groupBy(array, 'WarehouseId');
```

Gives you ->

```
wareHouseId1: [...], 
wareHouseId2: [...]
```

Multi-level grouping is not supported by library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to solve this problem

```js
let groupBy = function(array, key) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    (result[item[key]] = result[item[key]] || []).push(item);
    return result;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(yourarray, 'yourkey'));
```

Comment: dose key can have multiple properties?

Comment: according to the given answer only one key might be able to add