# How to map an array of nested arrays grouped by desired object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of messages which are like the following:

```
[
  { message: 'This is message', to: 4, from: 1},
  { message: 'This is response message', to: 1, from: 4 },
  { message: 'This is ANOTHER message with different sender', to: 1, from: 2 },
  { message: 'This is RESPONSE message to different sender', to: 2, from: 1 },
]
```

I have all the messages, but they are not grouped by the user-to-user conversation. What I want is to group the messages (inside an array) by `to` and `from`.

How can I achieve the following outcome:

```
[
  [
    { message: 'This is message', to: 4, from: 1},
    { message: 'This is response message', to: 1, from: 4 },
  ],
  [
    { message: 'This is ANOTHER message with different sender', to: 1, from: 2 },
    { message: 'This is RESPONSE message to different sender', to: 2, from: 1 }
  ],
]
```

In short:

Current structure is

```
// Individually structured messages
[message, message, message, message]
```

Desired outcome:

```
// Grouped by user-to-user conversation
// [[Conversation1], [Conversation2]]
[[message, message], [message,message]]
```

I have tried using lodash with  `return this._.values(this._.groupBy(this.messages, 'to'))`, but since I need to group them by two criteria, I didn't manage to come up with the logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group an array of objects based on multiple keys in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624567/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-based-on-multiple-keys-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript implementation with `Array.reduce` and `Array.find`

```js
const messages = [
  { message: 'This is message', to: 4, from: 1},
  { message: 'This is response message', to: 1, from: 4 },
  { message: 'This is ANOTHER message with different sender', to: 1, from: 2 },
  { message: 'This is RESPONSE message to different sender', to: 2, from: 1 },
];
const groupedMessage = messages.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find(item => item.find((msg) => (msg.from === curr.to && msg.to === curr.from) || (msg.from === curr.from && msg.to === curr.to)));
  node ? node.push(curr) : acc.push([curr]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(groupedMessage);
```

Comment: This works! Only thing is that I forgot to give an example that there is a case where the conversation is only 1 sided. For example: 

`Hey Good morning! (to : 4, from 2)
Are you there? (to : 4, from 2)
Please answer? (to : 4, from 2)`

Comment: @BerinAptula Updated the answert, please check.

Comment: This solved my challenge. Thanks!