# How to get repeated objects in json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like this :

```js
var data = [
      {title: "HH02"},
      {title: "HH03"},
      {title: "HH04"},
      {title: "HH02"},
      {title: "HH07"},
      {title: "HH08"},
      {title: "HH08"},
      {title: "HH10"},
      {title: "HH02"},
      {title: "HH11"}
]
```

First I would like to get repeated objects in JSON array like this:

```js
var output = [
     {title: "HH02" },
     {title: "HH08" },
]
```

Then I would like to get all repeated objects and how many times they are repeated in another JSON array like this

```js
var output = [
     {title: "HH02" , repeat: 3},
     {title: "HH08" , repeat: 2},
]
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't work well:

```js
data.map(v => v.title).sort().sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a === b) output.push(a);
                })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce, filter and map`

- Group all the values by `title` first, count there repetition
- Filter the `titles` which appears once or less then once ( exclude them )
- map them to get desired output

```js
var data = [{title: "HH02"},{title: "HH03"},{title: "HH04"},{title: "HH02"},{title: "HH07"},{title: "HH08"},{title: "HH08"},{title: "HH10"},{title: "HH02"},{title: "HH11"}]

let final = [...data.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let title = inp.title
  op.set(title, (op.get(title) || 0) + 1)
  return op
}, new Map()).entries()].filter(([_,repeat]) => repeat > 1).map(([title, repeat]) => ({
  title,
  repeat
}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count repeated objects with `reduce` and filter them out with `filter`

```
Object.values(data.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const repeat = acc[value.title] ? acc[value.title].repeat + 1 : 1;
  acc[value.title] = { repeat: repeat, ...value };
  return acc;
}, {})).filter(value => value.repeat > 1);
```

Comment: You should add some commentary. Code-only answers are not good quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **lodash** groupBy for that.

Here is the link https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

It will return a JSON object with titles as key and the array of items under that key as its value.

The length of that value will return the required count.

Answer (score 0):

I would never suggest having side effects in a sort callback other than sorting the array itself. Try a reduce followed by a filter and map on `Object.keys(...)`:

```
const countMap = data.reduce((result, element) => {
    result[element.title] = (result[element.title] || 0) + 1;
    return result;
}, {});
const result = Object.keys(countMap).filter(title => countMap[title] > 1).map(title => {
    return {title, repeat: countMap[title]};
});
```