# get duplicates in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects.

```js
let coordinates = [
    { x: 8, y: 1 },
    { x: 8, y: 3 },
    { x: 6, y: 5 },
    { x: 4, y: 6 },
    { x: 3, y: 7 },
    { x: 6, y: 5 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 },
    { x: 1, y: 4 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 }
]
```

I stumbled upon this [blog](https://raymonschouwenaar.nl/find-duplicate-property-values-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects/53212154) but it only lets me find duplicates based on one property but I want to get the duplicate objects based on `x` and `y` properties like this:

```
[
    { x: 6, y: 5 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 }
]
```

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: @brk it's in the last part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers are not fully correct, because they don't apply to arrays with more than 2 duplicates of the same value, i.e.:

```
var coordinates = [
  { x: 8, y: 1 },
  { x: 8, y: 1 },
  { x: 8, y: 1 }
]
```

I used `JSON.stringify()` and Set structure to get unique duplicates from an array. And for the output I parsed strings back to the objects.

```js
var coordinates = [
      { x: 8, y: 1 },
      { x: 6, y: 5 },
      { x: 4, y: 6 },
      { x: 3, y: 7 },
      { x: 6, y: 5 },
      { x: 3, y: 3 },
      { x: 1, y: 4 },
      { x: 3, y: 3 },
      { x: 3, y: 3 },
]
    
const duplicates = new Set();
const reducer = (set, val, index, arr) => arr.findIndex(k => k.x == val.x && k.y == val.y) != index ? set.add(JSON.stringify(val)) : set
    
coordinates.reduce(reducer, duplicates)
    
console.log(Array.from(duplicates).map(el => JSON.parse(el)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We apply filter to check the uniquness of index, say if element is duplicate it will count the initial index and the current index will be filtered out.

```js
var coordinates = [ { x: 8, y: 1 }, { x: 6, y: 5 }, { x: 4, y: 6 }, { x: 3, y: 7 }, { x: 6, y: 5 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 1, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }];

var result = coordinates.filter((val, i, self)=>self.findIndex(k=>k.x==val.x && k.y == val.y)!=i);

console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE**

```js
coordinates = [ { x: 6, y: 5 }, { x: 6, y: 5 }, { x: 6, y: 5 },{ x: 4, y: 6 }, { x: 3, y: 7 }, { x: 6, y: 5 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 1, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 3 },{ x: 6, y: 5 }];

result = coordinates.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  key = Object.values(elem).join('|');
  acc.unique[key] = acc.unique[key] || [];
  acc.unique[key].length >0 ? acc.duplicate[key] = elem : acc.unique[key].push(elem);
  return acc;
},{unique:{},duplicate:{}});

duplicate = Object.values(result.duplicate);
unique = Object.values(result.unique);

console.log(duplicate);
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: @breekoy Also if you look at `filter` function it accepts various arguments such as `(val, i, self)` `val` representing current iteration element, `i` representing `index count` and `self` is the `array itself`.

Comment: This is wrong answer. It breaks with array consists of duplicates more than 2 `var coordinates = [
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and another array. Inside reduce callback use x & y to create an object key and check if that key exist in accumulator object. If it exist then push tyhe value to the `dupArray`

```js
let coordinates = [
  { x: 8, y: 1 },
  { x: 8, y: 3 },
  { x: 6, y: 5 },
  { x: 4, y: 6 },
  { x: 3, y: 7 },
  { x: 6, y: 5 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 4 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 }
];
let dupArray = [];
let dups = coordinates.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const crtKey = '' + curr.x + '' + curr.y;
  if (!acc[crtKey]) {
    acc[crtKey] = 1;
  } else {
    dupArray.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(dupArray)
```

Comment: I think that the first `''` before `+ curr.x` is redundant

Comment: @zb22 because i want the key to be string otherwise key weill be numeric for example a key like 9(6+3) or 9(5+4) will be same, which will give wrong result

Comment: yes, but the `curr.x + '' + curr.y` makes it to be a string, once you put the `''` between them

Comment: @zb22 middle or beginning does that matter?

Comment: it doesn't, so I think one of them is redundant

Comment: This answer also breaks with more than 2 duplicates `var coordinates = [ { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }, ]`

Comment: @Tajni what do you mean by break?

Comment: Returns duplicated duplicates. Try with my array.

Comment: @Tajni does the expected answer says anything for that?

Comment: This is intuitive when we want duplicates, we don't need duplicated duplicates. Only unique duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

this filters only the duplicate array Objects by iterating all the Array items and for each item, iterating the Array again, using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if that specific item was anywhere in the array (`arr`) in a location **before** the current one (`idx1`) and also comparing the current item with the checked items in the *some iterator* by casting both to *"string"*

```js
let coordinates = [
    { x: 8, y: 1 },
    { x: 8, y: 3 },
    { x: 6, y: 5 },
    { x: 4, y: 6 },
    { x: 3, y: 7 },
    { x: 6, y: 5 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 },
    { x: 1, y: 4 },
    { x: 3, y: 3 }
]

const dups = coordinates.filter(({x, y}, idx1, arr) => 
    arr.some(({x:x2,y:y2}, idx2) => idx2 < idx1 && ""+x+y == ""+x2+y2 ) 
)

console.log( dups )
```

To make the check more **robust**, by allowing comparison of any key, what-so-ever [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can be used to compare the arrays (assuming all array items are *Objects*:

```js
const dups = coordinates.filter((item, idx1, arr) => 
   arr.some((item2, idx2) => idx2 < idx1 && JSON.stringify(item) == JSON.stringify(item2))
```