# How to dedupe an array of objects by a key value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
// This is a large array of objects, e.g.:
let totalArray = [
    {"id":"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4","fields":
    {"user_id":170180717,"user_name":"abcdefg","event_id":516575,
    }]

let uniqueArray = [];

let dupeArray = [];

let itemIndex = 0

totalArray.forEach(x => {
  if(!uniqueArray.some(y => JSON.stringify(y) === JSON.stringify(x))){
    uniqueArray.push(x)
  } else(dupeArray.push(x))
})

node.warn(totalArray);
node.warn(uniqueArray);
node.warn(dupeArray);

return msg;
```

I need my code to identify duplicates in the array by a key value of **user_id** within the objects in the array. Right now, my code works to identify identical objects in the array, but I need it to identify dupes based on a key value inside the objects instead. How do I do this? I am struggling to figure out how to path the for each loop to identify the dupe based on the key value instead of the entire object.

Comment: You could sort the array, then you only need to compare with the previous item.

Comment: do you want to take the first found same id into unique?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983043/104380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now, my code works to identify identical objects in the array, but I need it to identify dupes based on a key value inside the objects instead. How do I do this?

Don’t compare the JSON representation of the whole objects then, but only their `user_id` property specifically.

```
totalArray.forEach(x => {
  if(!uniqueArray.some(y => y.fields.user_id === x.fields.user_id)){
    uniqueArray.push(x)
  } else(dupeArray.push(x))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Set` and push to either uniques or duplicates.

```js
var array = [
        { id: 1, data: 0 },
        { id: 2, data: 1 },
        { id: 2, data: 2 },
        { id: 3, data: 3 },
        { id: 3, data: 4 },
        { id: 3, data: 5 },
    ],
    uniques = [],
    duplicates = [];

array.forEach(
    (s => o => s.has(o.id) ? duplicates.push(o) : (s.add(o.id), uniques.push(o)))
    (new Set)
);

console.log(uniques);
console.log(duplicates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a list of ids you found so far and act accordingly:

```js
totalArray = [
  { id: 1, val: 10 },
  { id: 2, val: 20 },
  { id: 3, val: 30 },
  { id: 2, val: 15 },
  { id: 1, val: 50 }
]
const uniqueArray = []
const dupeArray = []
const ids = {}
totalArray.forEach( x => {
  if (ids[x.id]) {
    dupeArray.push(x)
  } else { 
    uniqueArray.push(x)
    ids[x.id] = true
  }
})
for (const obj of uniqueArray) console.log("unique:",JSON.stringify(obj))
for (const obj of dupeArray)   console.log("dupes: ",JSON.stringify(obj))
```