# Get list of duplicate objects in an array based on two property in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to get duplicate objects within an array based on 2 properties. Let's say the object is like below.

```
let arry = [
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-2", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-3", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-4", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-5", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-2", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-6", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-7", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-6", Status: "approved"},
]
```

Duplicate objects should return and only the Status "approved" once like below:

```
[
{Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
 {Level: "A-2", Status: "approved"}
]
```

Comment: _"I am trying..."_ - So, what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to keep track of all the previous items as it iterates through the array, while preserving only the ones it's seen before (whose `Status` is `"approved"`).

In order to not output duplicates of duplicates, it also checks if the current duplicate was already found as a duplicate, and ignores it if so.

```js
const array = [
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-2", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-3", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-4", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-5", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-2", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-6", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-7", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-6", Status: "approved" },
];

const dupes = array.reduce((dupes, { Level, Status }, i) => {
  const matches = ({ Level: l, Status: s }) => l == Level && s == Status;
  const match = dupes.memory.find(matches);
  const found = dupes.dupes.find(matches);
  (match?.Status == 'approved' && !found)
    ? dupes.dupes.push({ Level, Status })
    : dupes.memory.push({ Level, Status });
  return (i == array.length - 1) ? dupes.dupes : dupes;
}, { dupes: [], memory: [] });

console.log(dupes);
```

A less general but more terse strategy might be:

```js
const dupes = [...new Set(array
  .filter(({ Status: s }) => s == 'approved')
  .map(({ Level: l }) => +l.match(/\d+/)[0])
  .filter((num, _, arr) => arr.filter((n) => n == num).length > 1))]
  .map((n) => ({ Level: 'A-' + n, Status: 'approved' }));
```

For example:

```js
const array = [
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-2", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-3", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-4", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-5", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-2", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-6", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-7", Status: "reject" },
  { Level: "A-1", Status: "approved" },
  { Level: "A-6", Status: "approved" },
];

const dupes = [...new Set(array
  .filter(({ Status: s }) => s == 'approved')
  .map(({ Level: l }) => +l.match(/\d+/)[0])
  .filter((num, _, arr) => arr.filter((n) => n == num).length > 1))]
  .map((n) => ({ Level: 'A-' + n, Status: 'approved' }));

console.log(dupes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arry = [
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-2", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-3", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-4", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-5", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-2", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-6", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-7", Status: "reject"},
    {Level: "A-1", Status: "approved"},
    {Level: "A-6", Status: "approved"},
]

function dups(arry) {
  const hashMap = {};

  return arry.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const level = curr.Level;
    if(hashMap[level] && hashMap[level] === 1 && curr.Status === 'approved') {
      acc.push(curr);
      hashMap[level]++;
    } else {
      hashMap[level] = 1;
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(dups(arry));
```