# Return objects with duplicate properties to a new array

Tags: javascript

I've seen a lot of examples that show how to filter/remove duplicate values from array, but I want to get the duplicates and use them in a new array. So for

```
array = [
    { id: '1', description: 'foo'},
    { id: '2', description: 'bar'},
    { id: '3', description: 'bloop'},
    { id: '1', description: 'bleep'}
]
```

I want a new array returned that only contains items with matching Id's like so

```
[
  { id: '1', description: 'foo'},
  { id: '1', description: 'bleep'}
]
```

I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it

Edit: The suggestions do not do what I'm asking for. They are either creating lookup tables or removing the items from the original array.

Comment: Checked this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects/53212154

Comment: Id equation is enough for you?

Comment: Neither of these solutions do what I am asking

Comment: @ChristopherMellor you claim that your question is substantially different from the suggested duplicate.  (i.e. the accepted answer just creates a "lookup table.")  However, the answer you have accepted here is functionally identical to the answer accepted over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
array = [
    { id: '1', description: 'foo'},
    { id: '2', description: 'bar'},
    { id: '3', description: 'bloop'},
    { id: '1', description: 'bleep'}
]

const duplicates = array.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.id] = ++a[e.id] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(array.filter(e => duplicates[e.id]));
```