# Remove all instances of duplicate objects in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I'm trying to remove all instances of duplicate objects in a javascript array. The helper function below works well for removing duplicates and keeping 1 instance, but I want to basically disqualify any object that has an equal property to another object by removing all instances.

```js
function removeDuplicates(data, key) {
    return [
        ... new Map(
            data.map(x => [key(x), x])
        ).values()
    ]
}
```

Example of uncleaned array:

```
[
  {
    name: 'name1',
    value: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 16
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    value: 17
  },
  {
    name: 'name1',
    value: 18
  }
]
```

Returned from above helper function:

```
[
  {
    name: 'name1',
    value: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 16
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    value: 17
  }
]
```

What I'd like to be returned:

```
[
  {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 16
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    value: 17
  }
]
```

Would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: What if two `value`s are the same? Is it just the `name` key? Can you use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects/53212154#53212154) but invert the condition and change `id` to `name` to match your key, i.e. `values.filter(e => !lookup[e.name])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your intention was to call the function above in this manner: `removeDuplicates(data, (x) => x.name)`, here is my implementation

```
function removeDuplicates(data, key) {
    return data.filter((o, idx) => {
        const remainingData = [...data.slice(0, idx), ...data.slice(idx + 1)];
        return !remainingData.some(o2 => key(o) === key(o2));
    });
}
```

Basically, for each element in the data array, I check for the remaining values, if there is another element with the same "key". I use the ["some" method for Javascript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test this. Only values that don't pass this test are returned by the filter function.

---

As some have noted - this is not the most efficient solution, so let me provide a better implementation:

```
function removeDuplicatesBetter(data, key) {
    return data.filter((o, idx) => {
        return !data.some((o2, idx2) => idx !== idx2 && key(o) === key(o2));
    });
}
```

---

Here is a Repl.it demonstrating the solutions: https://replit.com/@VehpuS/removeDuplicates

Comment: This was a very complex approach to this problem since you are filtering it twice anyways and also creating a list of objects in every iteration. (i did not vote ur anwer down)

Comment: While I agree, at least for the size of input provided, performance is less of an issue :). But fair enough - I'll add a more efficient implementation

Comment: The second solution works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr, key) {
    const duplicates = arr.reduce((seen, obj) => ((seen[obj[key]] = seen.hasOwnProperty(obj[key])), seen), {});
    return arr.filter((obj) => !duplicates[obj[key]]);
}

//Usage: 
const input = [
    {
        name: "name1",
        value: 15,
    },
    {
        name: "name2",
        value: 16,
    },
    {
        name: "name3",
        value: 17,
    },
    {
        name: "name1",
        value: 18,
    },
];

const output = removeDuplicates(input, "name");

console.log(output);
//output: [ { name: 'name2', value: 16 }, { name: 'name3', value: 17 } ]
```