# Compare objects within an array and create a new array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, reduce

I've an array of objects:

```
[
  { name: "John", age: "34" },
  { name: "Ace", age: "14" },
  { name: "John", age: "45" },
  { name: "Harry", age: "11" },
]
```

I want to compare the objects within an array by name. If the duplicate name exists, I should compare the age and only keep the higher age object.

The expected output should be:

```
[
  { name: "Ace", age: "14" },
  { name: "John", age: "45" },
  { name: "Harry", age: "11" },
]
```

I am new to javascript/typescript and couldn't find any optimal solution for this problem. I hope, I was able to explain my problem clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects can help you

Comment: I feel like there will be some crazy one liner using `.map()`

Comment: @Panomosh do you mean like `[...data.reduce( (acc, val) => +(acc.get(val.name)?.age ?? 0) > +val.age ? acc : acc.set(val.name, val), new Map() ).values()]` ? :)

Comment: It's slightly annoying that the ages are stored as strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
var objArr=...your json object;
var maxValueGroup = "name";
var maxValueName = "age";
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr(objArr,maxValueGroup, maxValueName)));
```

newArr

```
var newArr = function (objArr,maxValueGroup, maxValueName) {
  var arr = groupBy(objArr, maxValueGroup);
  var newArr = [];
  $.each(arr, function (key) {
    var maxVal = 0;
    var maxValItem;
    arr[key].forEach((element) => {
      if (element[maxValueName] > maxVal) {
        maxVal = element[maxValueName];
        maxValItem = element;
      }
    });
    newArr.push(maxValItem);
  });
  return newArr;
};
```

groupby

```
var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: Since the `age` values are stored as strings one needs to cast them into number values at comparison time otherwise one runs into falsely compared items. And what is, without need, the jquery `each` for? In addition, an executable stack snippet enables everyone (including the one having provided the answer) to immediately verify/check the implemented example code.

Comment: @PeterSeliger It is OP problem. I am not a free coder,  I just give some hints and I don't think that it is a real json to waste time for a validation.

Comment: I cannot set the value of maxValue. dynamically my code should be able to find out, For eg: This is my response after group by. (I've kept the age as number now, just to avoid the confusion of validation): Response:  'harry': [ {
      name: 'harry',
      age: 33,
    }, {
        name: 'harry',
        age: 43,
    }
] Now dynamically I want to compare the age of 2 objects, and keep the one with max age. I hope i am clear with what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @utSharma You don't need to set maxValue. it is a temporary variable. This function can be used for any array of objects with any names of properties.  All you need to set the names of properties -" name" and "age" in this case. But if you have only one array with this names. you can just hardcoded it .  I tested this code and everything is working properly. I don't understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```js
const obj = [{ name: "John", age: "34" }, { name: "Ace", age: "14" }, { name: "John", age: "45" }, { name: "Harry", age: "11" }];
const objCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

const res = objCopy.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const personExist = acc.find(({ name }) => name === obj.name);
  if (personExist) {
    if (parseInt(obj.age, 10) > parseInt(personExist.age, 10)) {
        personExist.age = obj.age;
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log({ res });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since the `age` items are string values one needs to cast them into number values at comparison time. The reason the above code seems to work in terms of comparison is due to pure luck with the test data (one time comparison of `"34"` vs `"45"`).

Comment: yes didnt see that

Comment: And just as overall note and not to be understood as critique of the above approach ... The `find` approach within the `reduce` task will become less and less efficient the more the database growth in terms of item name variety due to `find` iterating an array itself (though it exits the iteration early). Thus the above approach is totally sufficient for probably almost all use cases in practice unless applied within environments of expansive data.

Comment: This solution isn't working. `acc`is an object, hence it is not allowing obj to use .find method

Comment: Hum, no. acc default value is '[]', which is an object but an array too.

Answer (score 0):

The next provided approach uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and creates in a first step just an index/map of items of highest age which are each unique by name. Thus one could use the temporary state of the programmatically built `result` as lookup for already existing `name`d items.

Within a second step one would retrieve the array of unique named items of highest age by passing such an index to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
function collectHighestAgeItemOfSameName(result, item) {
  const { name, age } = item;
  if (
    !(name in result) ||
    Number(result[name].age) < Number(age)
  ) {
    result[name] = item;
  }
  return result;
}

const sampleData = [{
  name: "John",
  age: "34"
}, {
  name: "Ace",
  age: "14"
}, {
  name: "Harry",
  age: "9"
}, {
  name: "John",
  age: "45"
}, {
  name: "Harry",
  age: "11"
}, {
  name: "Ace",
  age: "13"
}];

console.log(
  'reduced index of unique person items of highest age ...',
  sampleData
    .reduce(collectHighestAgeItemOfSameName, {})
)
console.log(
  'array of unique person items of highest age ...',
  Object
    .values(
      sampleData
        .reduce(collectHighestAgeItemOfSameName, {})
    )
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

This works basically the same as @PeterSeliger's fine and upvote-worthy answer, except it uses a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object which is nice because [Map.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) returns the Map object, allowing you to return it as the accumulator for the next iteration of the reduce function.

```js
const data = [{name: "John", age: "34"}, {name: "Ace", age: "14"}, {name: "John", age: "45"}, {name: "Harry", age: "11"}];

const res = [...data.reduce(
  (acc, val) =>
    +(acc.get(val.name)?.age ?? -1) >= +val.age ?
      acc :
      acc.set(val.name, val),
  new Map()
).values()];

console.log(JSON.stringify( res ));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Other references:**

1. [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)
2. [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
3. [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
4. [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
5. [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
6. [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)