# how to get multiple duplicate data in array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

this arrary have multiple duplicate data

`var = [{id: 1, name:'jeff'}{id:1, name:'kent'}{id:2, name:'ynez'}{id:2, name:'cloe'}{id:3, name:'Ron'}{id:3, name:'chester'}]`

i need like this in return i need only id: 1 like this

`duplicate = [{id:1, name:'jeff'}{id:1, name:'kent'}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: i already check that question but the senario is i have multiple duplicate data in array and i need only one duplicate data just like in my post

Comment: Do you want to treat var as string? Because syntax misting commas between objects inside array.

Comment: *"i need only id: 1"* -> [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: No sir Mohsin Ali my wrong about commas, in the data above i need to get the data of same id:1

Comment: Just like this, right?
obj_var = [{id: 1, name:'jeff'},{id:1, name:'kent'},{id:2, name:'ynez'},{id:2, name:'cloe'},{id:3, name:'Ron'},{id:3, name:'chester'}]

Comment: yes but i need to get the same id: 1 like this duplicate = [{id:1, name:'jeff'}{id:1, name:'kent'}]

Comment: It will give you the array of objects that are duplicate (by id):

var obj_var = [{id: 1, name:'jeff'},{id:1, name:'kent'},{id:2, name:'ynez'},{id:2, name:'cloe'},{id:3, name:'Ron'},{id:3, name:'chester'}];

var duplicate = Object.entries(obj_var.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if(!acc[cur.id]) acc[cur.id] = [];

    acc[cur.id].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, {})).filter(([key, value]) => value.length > 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list = [{id: 1, name:'jeff'},{id:1, name:'kent'},{id:2, name:'ynez'},{id:2, name:'cloe'},{id:3, name:'Ron'},{id:3, name:'chester'}]

const findDuplicateId = 1
const tempArray = []
list.forEach((lf) => {
  if(lf.id === findDuplicateId){
    tempArray.push(lf);
  }
})

console.log(tempArray)

console.log(tempArray.length > 1 ? 'duplicate' : 'not duplicate')
```

Comment: Any reason why you reinvent the wheel? `const tempArray = list.filter(item => item.id === 1);`

Comment: @Thomas
had voted for close, 
then saw that questioner is BEGINNER,
also question had LITTLE VARIATION
questioner was finding difficult to grasp ans 
so , reinvented the WHEEL