# return objects with matching ids, but in one exemplar

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I've got an array of objects. All I want is to check if the ids of the objects are the same and return that particular object, without duplication.

example.

```
let arr1 = [
{id: 1, name: 'A'},
{id: 3, name: 'C'},
{id: 1, name: 'A'},
{id: 2, name: 'B'},
{id: 2, name: 'B'}
]
```

result I want:

```
let newArr = [
{id: 1, name: 'A'},
{id: 2, name: 'B'}
]
```

result I get:

```
let arr1 = [
{id: 1, name: 'A'},
{id: 3, name: 'C'},
{id: 2, name: 'B'}
]
```

I tried:

```
arr1.reduce((destArray, obj) => {
    if (destArray.findIndex(i => i.id === obj.id) < 0) {
      return destArray.concat(obj);
    } else {
      return destArray;
    }
  }, [])
```

As a result, I get objects with matching ids, BUT there're also objects with kinda unique id. But I don't need them.

Comment: You said that you don't want duplicates, and the result you got does not contain any. What's the problem then?

Comment: Sounds like you want to retrieve all the duplicates, from `result I want` example.

Comment: possibly see: [Get list of duplicate objects in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212020/get-list-of-duplicate-objects-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newArr = arr1.filter((obj, index, self) => {
return self.findIndex(i => i.id === obj.id) === index && self.lastIndexOf(i => i.id === obj.id) !== index;
});
```

Comment: Please explain how your code solved OP's problem

Comment: The question is actually asking for items that are duplicated it seems, or it's contradicting itself, and there are not enough details to answer it.